# Bigquery standardSQL: Current date minus a previous date with a result in number of days?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to the current date minus a previous begin date with the result with the result being the number days there is a difference of the two?

I have attempted the following: date_sub(Begindt, INTERVAL current_date)

Also, will I have to cast things differently?

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), Begindt, DAY)
```

See more for [DATE_DIFF()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff)

Above assumes the `Begindt` field is of DATE type
If not, you should cast to DATE type via `CAST` or [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) functions

Answer (score 0):

Are you finding something like below

```
DATE_DIFF(Begindt, CURRENT_DATE, day)
```

Comment: The function is 'DATE_DIFF'